# Blazor format an InputType of Numeric

Tags: blazor, asp.net-blazor

Would anyone know how to format a Numeric type to look like 100.10? Currently if the value is 100.10 it will display as 100.1

tried @bind-value:format with C2, 0:0.##, I'm new to Blazor so if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

```
<BSBasicInput InputType="InputType.Number" @bind-Value="@Amount" step="0.01" />
```

Answer (score 5):

If you bind to a `decimal` it seems it will keep the number of decimals you specify for the value, even training zeros.

```
@page "/"
<EditForm Model=@Account>
    <InputNumber @bind-Value=Account.Balance/>
    <button>Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code
{
    BankAccount Account = new BankAccount();

    public class BankAccount
    {
        public decimal Balance { get; set; } = 23.300;
    }
}
```

For floats and doubles I would have expected the following to work

```
<InputNumber @bind-Value=Account.Balance @bind-Value:format="F2"/>
```

But it seems only `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` are supported, which is a shame.

There is an example on Blazor University showing how to descend from `InputBase` to create your own input controls. It would be quite trivial to implement a control that honours the format.

https://blazor-university.com/forms/descending-from-inputbase/

Comment: It does keep the decimals at first but if the up arrow is clicked and it does a step of 0.01 going from 101.09 to 101.10 that's when the ending zero disappears

Comment: There is the MudBlazor Numeric Field, perhaps it can help https://www.mudblazor.com/components/numericfield#basic-numeric-fields

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this for some time, using ToString, etc.  Today, I looked at how it built the format string for the Grid column (I used FormatString setting as Currency there).

Long story short, after some trial and error, I simply put "0.00" in the format string and it shows 2 decimal places!  I also found that I could put "$0.00" and it places the $ at the start of the string!

This is just the Format entry on the Properties for the numeric field!