# Format InputNumber as percent

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have a model bound to an edit form.  One of the properties of the model is a decimal as percent.  I would like to show the user, and allow them to type things like:

10.5
instead of
.015

Is there an InputNumber formatter? I'd be ok with a third party nuget to manage this as well.
This is an over-simplified code sample

```
<EditForm Model="@Model">
<InputNumber @bind-Value="Model.PercentValue" />
</EditForm>
```

Comment: With decimal, this should solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62073358/blazor-format-an-inputtype-of-numeric

Comment: @RoarS. thanks for the comment, but that's not a solution.  the value is actually .015 and I want it to display as 10.5% or 10.5

Comment: @Kevon Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: As a hack, I was thinking (beyond using a DTO) to put a `[NotMapped]` property on the entity and with its getter multiply the actual property by 100, the reverse with its setter. If anyone's interested in a polished solution, leave a comment, I'll make a custom Blazor Component for this (in .NET 8!! Should be dropping soon today!!)

Comment: @MikeT I have not found a good solution

Comment: @Kevon The answer I provided should solve your issue, if not let me know, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file, name it InputPercent.razor, then paste this code into it:

```
@typeparam TNullableNumber
@inherits InputBase<TNullableNumber>
<div class="input-group">
    <input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
           class="form-control"
           inputmode="decimal"
           @onchange="valueChanged"
           type="number"
           value="@percent" />
    <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
</div>

@code {
    decimal percent = 0;
    Type type;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TNullableNumber)) ?? typeof(TNullableNumber);

        percent = (decimal)(object)CurrentValue * 100;
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out TNullableNumber result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void valueChanged(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        var val = args.Value.ToString();

        if (type == typeof(float) && float.TryParse(val, out float resultFloat))
        {
            CurrentValue = (TNullableNumber)(object)(resultFloat / 100);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(double) && double.TryParse(val, out double resultDouble))
        {
            CurrentValue = (TNullableNumber)(object)(resultDouble / 100);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(decimal) && decimal.TryParse(val, out decimal resultDecimal))
        {
            CurrentValue = (TNullableNumber)(object)(resultDecimal / 100);
        }
        else throw new InvalidCastException("Only float, double, and decimal types can be used for the InputPercent component");
    }
}
```

I threw in some Bootstrap stuff, if you don't use Bootstrap, just delete it.

I didn't double-check that it works with nullable float, double, decimal types, fingers crossed.

Use it like any Input Component:

```
<InputPercent @bind-Value="MyClass.MyPercentValue" />
```